Context propagation using project reactor
I'm trying to leverage context propagation for MDC using project reactor. I've read the official docu and also went through a nice blog series https://spring.io/blog/2023/03/28/context-propagation-with-project-reactor-1-the-basics, still in my simple example it seems I'm missing something.
In my MyOutboundHandler I need to access requestId, which when I call the endpoint I successfully get. In #MyOutboundHandler.channelRead method I'm clearing the MDC context and then after I call the endpoint again, the requestId is empty. Also I've tried to clear the MDC in .doFinally, but the result is the same, everything after the first call is always null. WebClientConfig is also present
What am I missing? Any hint much appreciated

You are adding it to the context in a wrong way. At the moment you are adding it the MDC (or the one tied to that thread) is already empty. You would need to directly add the requestId not delay it as you do now. something like ctx.put(requestId, requestId) that will link it to the actual request id.

@M.Deinum I'm not sure I get it, could you be more specific where I should add it? Even if I put ctx.put(requestId, requestId) inside of .contextWrite, the context in second call to the endpoint is still empty. Thnx

If it is empty you aren't passing the header to the controller.
